# Google Play Services Phone Number Hint is not working on some devices

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services

I'm trying to use Phone number Hint api from google play services. Its working fine on some devices and not working in some devices.

I'm following this as reference [Phone number hint](https://developers.google.com/identity/phone-number-hint/android)

Not working specially on Samsung Android devices with Android 12.